Sourcing a shell script vs. Passing it as an argument to a shell interpreter
I'm new in shell scripting. As I discovered today, there are at least three ways to run a shell script:

To execute it, using the absolute or a relative path:

/folder1/folder2/script.sh
./script.sh

The disadvantage is that you need to grant it executable permissions first: chmod +x ./script.sh.

To source it, using . or source.

Though sometimes source is just an alias to ., sometimes, e.g., in Zsh, they work differenlty. For details, see an answer by Stéphane Chazelas.


. ./script.sh (And not just . script.sh. For details, see an answer by AdminBee.)

source ./script.sh

In Zsh, accoding to the linked answers by Stéphane Chazelas and AdminBee, it is probably better, from a puristic point of view, to use source script.sh instead, though I'm not really sure.




To pass it as an argument to a shell interpreter.

zsh script.sh



What are the practical differences between sourcing it and passing it as an argument to a shell interpreter? Which way is better from both practical and puristic points of view?

I think the answers to the duplicate should have all the info you need. Please let me know if not, edit the question to point out what's missing, and we can reopen it.

@terdon I don't see the difference between the 2nd and 3rd approaches is explained there. The 3rd approach seems to be not mentioned there.

Ah OK, does this help? What is the difference between running "bash script.sh" and "./script.sh"? (for some reason, I cannot add it as a dupe target, some bug).

@terdon And this one is about the difference between the 1st and 3rd approaches. The 2nd approach is merely mentioned in comments, but there is no related discussion. So it is not clear from that link how #2 and #3 differs.

The dupe target explains the difference between sourcing and executing, between 2 and either 1 or 3, both of which are just executing. Then, the other link explains the difference between executing directly (1) and executing by passing the script as an argument to a specific shell (3). 1 and 3 differ from 2 in exactly the same ways. There is no significant difference between 1 and 3 other than that with 3 you can specify a different shell. Isn't this clear from the answers?

@terdon It seems the linked answers require a higher level of understanding than mine. Now, with your explanation, the question is really answered. Thank you very much.

The "most correct" approach is to assign the script executable permissions and ensure it's either in your $PATH or that you run it as ./script.
My preference is to create a directory $HOME/bin and put my personal scripts there. For example,
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin"             # One-off: create the directory
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"    # One-off: add it to the end of your ~/.bash_profile

If you're using sh (or dash) rather than a newer shell like bash you will need to split the second line into two parts and add both to your $HOME/.profile file
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
export PATH

You can then create scripts such as mydemo (usually without a trailing .sh suffix) and have them run exactly as if they were standard system commands:
cat >"$HOME/bin/mydemo" <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
echo 'This is a demonstration of the "mydemo" command'
exit 0
EOF

chmod a+rx "$HOME/bin/mydemo"    # One-off: make it executable

Now you can run it just like date or ls, etc.:
mydemo

Notice that the script started with a #! line, telling the system what interpreter to use. In this case it was /bin/sh but a typical alternative is often /bin/bash.
The big advantages here are that:

You don't need to remember which interpreter is required for which script
All your scripts are in a well-known place
If other people using your Linux-based system wanted access to your scripts, you could move them to a directory that's in everyone's $PATH without any ill effect. I like /usr/local/bin but an alternative might be /opt/bin. Just remember not to use the same name as an existing command!

Remember that Windows, Mac, and Linux-based systems are all different. Don't try to use a Windows editor to create your script file and then expect it to run cleanly on a Linux-based system. (The line-endings are different.) There are common fixes for this situation but it's best to avoid it in the first place if you possibly can.
The other part of your question, about the difference between . (or source) and executing the script directly are explained at What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash

Hello, Chris. Many thanks for a very detailed answer. I'm on macOS. I really appreciate your detailed explanation of the first approach, but still: How does sourcing a script is different from passing a script as an argument?

@jsx97 looks like that's been addressed by the flagged duplicate. Come back to me in a comment here if that's not clear
